# Is it possible to use electron and nativefier to create native iOS App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, electron, web-deployment

Some time ago I started experimenting with Electron and the Nativefier tool to test the possibility of transferring web applications to native desktop applications.

Recently, I have begun to wonder if it is possible to use Electron and Nativefier to create native iOS App?

I am not strong when it comes to node.js, but I am very curious about this issue, so thank you very much for all the answers provided.

I would like my thread to be conducted as an open discussion among all of us.

[Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/)

[Nativefier Command Tool](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier)